# Quasar (vuejs) project with TypeScript show error when importing 3rd party libraries

Tags: typescript, importerror, quasar-framework

I have created a Quasar CLI project using TypeScript. It's all very impressing, but now I'm facing a problem importing 3rd party libraries (cheerio, jQuery or similar).

I have a Index.vue file, where I'm fetching HTML/XML from an API. I need to find different nodes in the HTML/XML based on classes etc., hence I thought of using jQuery or cheerio to CSS select the node(s) I need.

When importing cheerio:

```
import {cheerio} from 'cheerio';
```

I get the error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'cheerio'. 
'/node_modules/cheerio/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/cheerio` if it exists 
or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file 
containing `declare module 'cheerio';`Vetur(7016)
```

Installing cheerio types does not work:

```
npm install @types/cheerio
```

If I look into node_modules/@types, there is a cheerio/index.d.ts file

Any idea why this does not work out of the box with Quasar?